# Time slider progress bar not working in jwplayer

Tags: html

Seek bar(time slider progress) not working on streaming m3u8 video file using jwplayer. Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show some code mister :)

Answer (score 0):

Since m3u8 is a playlist format, i suppose you trying to play a bunch of .flv files. In this case, your files, which you are trying to play, should contain all metadata, such as size, duration, codec, etc.

The thing is, most of modern converters leave your files with no metadata, so player cannot show you things like pointer, or total time. You need to inject metadata manually, for example, using [flvmeta](https://flvmeta.com/).